# Justification for placing an army of supersoldiers under the control of an unstable psychic commander?

Tags: science-based, military, modern

Armchair Chem is your cookie-cutter evil corporation in one of my settings. They're primarily focused on military tech and behind the curtains, unethical experiments.

Their latest project was commissioned for the US Army. A battalion of supersoldiers, equipped with state-of-the-art technology.

Now, while there's combat expertise programmed into them, these replica soldiers have no real mind of their own, they're blank slates that together form a hivemind where individual soldiers can share enemy location and intel. This hivemind converges at the coordinator, Paxton Fettel.

So, Paxton isn't exactly what you'd call stable, in fact, he's moments away from snapping, and when that happens, best-case scenario, the replica army has to be shut down; worst-case scenario, he goes AWOL and slaughters everyone.

As the coordinator of the hive mind, Paxton can imprint himself on any of the soldiers, effectively giving himself a one-up and the combat expertise of that soldier. Furthermore, the connections within this hive mind can't really be tapped or jammed. The reason is a company secret.

---

So,  the first question I had was what kind of a moron would come up with an idea like that? Even if it worked, Paxton would be a power bottom, who is in complete control, despite being the one who, in paper, is receiving the orders.

And besides, it's just bad practice to allocate so much power into the hand of a single person.

**So, why would the modern-day US Armed Forces even decide to commission that?** Obviously, an entire battalion would probably be employed in live combat instead of just being very-expensive decoration or a tool for intimidation (their shortcoming would be too blatant then).

Comment: The corporation most likely knows that Paxton is nuts... but does the Army?

Comment: Are you saying that you have an expensive, unreliable, and potentially backfiring weapon without a useful mission?  That seems more like Congress than the Army: Perhaps Paxton has a lot of friends in Congress.

Comment: sound like the case of corruption there, or the case like Obama Bin Laden and his puppet army provide by america, or maybe america just want that to happen to create a justification for war.

Comment: btw if paxton die are the entire battalion die or goes vegetable? or you mean paxton can goes warg like in GOT?

Comment: @LiJun Paxton just downloads himself into another supersoldier.

Answer (score 4):

Becuse that is how US Army works.
You can't foresee what your enemy is doing if the enemy don't know it.
Also, a possible berserk super soldier division? Sign every general ever in. They know you cannot win a war with handful of, no matter how well trained and equipped soldiers. Sooner or later they will be bombed into oblivion. Or napalmed. Or burned. Or buried alive. YOu get the picture.
What they can hope for is for "or later" and during that time they will create enough havock and tie, as much as they can, enemy forces for the whole time.

And if they committ some war crimes? Welp, president will pardon them. Or not because we can just take new ones from a vat.

Or hey, even better. Leave them where they need to be and later bomb them ourself.

Consider your supersoldier to be Hiroo Onoda or Teruo Nakamura. Being able to fight for 30 years.